# Concat, join, merge. Problema con la aplicación de los métodos en una clase

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, anaconda

He definido éste método para una clase.

```
# DataFrame con índices y valores.
    def get_index_value_df(self):
        df1 = portfolio_r4_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
        df2 = self.yf_AdjClose_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
        #self. df_total = df1.join(df2)
        self.df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)        
        return self.df_total
```

He comprobado que los DataFrames que quiero unir, contienen datos. Cuando llamo al método me devuelve un DataFrame con solamente las columnas y valores en las columnas de **df1**.

Aplico a los DataFrames **df1** y **df2** las  estrategias de  interpolación o el relleno hacia adelante o hacia atrás para manejar los datos faltantes.

Compruebo que **start_date** y **end_date** están definidas correctamente en el ámbito del **método get_index_value_df()**.

Compruebo que  los DataFrames tienen los mismos índices y que contienen datos para el período de tiempo que deseo seleccionar.

Sospechando que es posible que algunos índices en **df2** no coinciden con los de **df1**, pruebo a utilizar el método **join** en lugar de **concat** para unir los DataFrames, dado que el método **join** realiza una unión en los índices y elimina automáticamente las filas que no tienen valores en ambos DataFrames.

```
def get_index_value_df(self):
    df1 = portfolio_r4_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    df2 = self.yf_AdjClose_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    self.df_total = df1.join(df2, how='inner')
    return self.df_total
```

Haciéndolo de ese modo, sigue devolviéndo  un DataFrame con las mismas columnas que **df1**, pero vacío.

A continuación pruebo con  el método **merge** en lugar de **join**, con la opción **how='inner'**. El objeto es  realizar una unión de los DataFrames **df1** y **df2** en función de sus índices **(left_index=True y right_index=True)**. Además, con la opción **how='inner'** garantizamos que solo se unan las filas con índices que coincidan en ambos DataFrames

```
def get_index_value_df(self):
    df1 = portfolio_r4_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    df2 = self.yf_AdjClose_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    self.df_total = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return self.df_total
```

Me devuelve lo mismo que con **join()**

A continuación pruebo utilizando  el método **concat** nuevamente, pero utilizando la **opción join='inner'** . la opción **join='inner'** asegura que solo se unan los índices que sean comunes en ambos DataFrames, eliminando automáticamente las filas que no tengan valores en ambos DataFrames. De esta manera, se deberían unir solo las filas con valores en ambos DataFrames.

```
def get_index_value_df(self):
    df1 = portfolio_r4_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    df2 = self.yf_AdjClose_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    self.df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
    return self.df_total
```

Sigue devolviendo lo mismo. lo mismo que con los dos anteriores

A continuación verifico, utilizando el método **pd.to_datetime** que los indices de ambos DataFrames están formateados de la misma manera.

```
def get_index_value_df(self):
    df1 = portfolio_r4_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    df2 = self.yf_AdjClose_df[self.start_date:self.end_date].ffill().bfill()
    df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
    df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
    self.df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
    return self.df_total
```

Sigue devolviendo lo mismo.

Si lo intento utilizando una función simple, fuera de la clase,opera correctamente.

```
def get_index_value_df():
    df1 = portfolio_r4_df[start_date:end_date].ffill().bfill()
    df2 = yf_AdjClose_df[start_date:end_date].ffill().bfill()
    df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
    df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
    df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
    return df_total

df_total = get_index_value_df()
df_total
```

Cuál puede ser la causa de éste fallo?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Hola efueyo, yo empesaría por modificar el return de **get_index_value_df** para que devuelva **df2**, y ver que tiene dentro.

Comment: Efectivamente, están vacíos. Tengo un pequeño lío con los nombres de los DataFrames (son muchos) de los métodos y su declaración en la clase. Voy a ver cómo lo puedo arreglar.

Comment: Resuelto, ese era el problema. Tu sugerencia me abrió los ojos. Gracias.

Comment: Maestro, un placer haberle ayudado.